# Failed to run Linkedin Norbert example

Tags: java, scala, linkedin-api, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to run Linked Norbert example from this [repo](https://github.com/linkedin/norbert).

I have java 7 on Ubuntu 16.06.

When I try to run test/package in sbt, it always failed to compile with 6 error

[errors message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnvUB.png)

Any one knows what's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

are you running the instructions? https://github.com/linkedin/norbert#building

Comment: Yes, I try to run the example with follow commands: ./sbt, project examples, package. While running package, I got the error. I also try clean then test/compile but not working